# R append columns in different ways

Tags: r, append

I have a dataset with multiple columns:

```
Value1 Value3 Annotation Value4 Value2
1        4        s        9       4
2        5        t        0       4
3        6        q        4       4
```

The order of the values and the position of `Annotation` is unknown.

Now I'm trying to append multiple columns and try to keep the `Annotation` correct. The result should be a 2 column matrix

eg. when I try to append `Value1` and `Value3`:

```
Annotation Valuelist
s             1
t             2
q             3
s             4
t             5
q             6
```

I found the method `append()` but I can't figure out how to make sure the annotation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stack` function might come in handy for what you want to do in base R:

```
cbind(mydf["Annotation"], stack(mydf[c("Value1", "Value3")])["values"])
#   Annotation values
# 1          s      1
# 2          t      2
# 3          q      3
# 4          s      4
# 5          t      5
# 6          q      6
```

`stack` normally creates two columns, "values" and "ind" (in that order), so we select just the first to match what you describe.

---

A similar approach can be taken with `melt` from "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
melt(mydf, id.vars="Annotation", 
     measure.vars=c("Value1", "Value3"))[c("Annotation", "value")]
#   Annotation value
# 1          s     1
# 2          t     2
# 3          q     3
# 4          s     4
# 5          t     5
# 6          q     6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could construct this with something like:

```
columns <- c("Value1", "Value3")
data.frame(Annotation=rep(dat$Annotation, length(columns)),
           Valuelist=as.vector(as.matrix(dat[columns])))
#   Annotation Valuelist
# 1          s         1
# 2          t         2
# 3          q         3
# 4          s         4
# 5          t         5
# 6          q         6
```

Comment: `rep` is unnecessary here because recycling will take care of that anyway, but +1 for an alternative!